# Protect against exceptions - PRAW

Tags: python, web-crawler, praw

Currently I have a script to download the top headlines from the front page of Reddit, and it works almost always. Occasionally I receive the exception below. I know that I should insert `try` and `except` statements to protect my code, but where should I put them?

**Crawl:**

```
def crawlReddit():                                                     
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='challenge')             # PRAW object
    topHeadlines = []                                   # List of headlines 
    for item in r.get_front_page():
        topHeadlines.append(item)                       # Add headlines to list
    return topHeadlines[0].title                            # Return top headline

def main():
    headline = crawlReddit()                            # Pull top headline

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makecall.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()                                      # Run
  File "makecall.py", line 53, in main
    headline = crawlReddit()                            # Pull top headline
  File "makecall.py", line 34, in crawlReddit
    for item in r.get_front_page():
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 480, in get_content
    page_data = self.request_json(url, params=params)
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/decorators.py", line 161, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 519, in request_json
    response = self._request(url, params, data)
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 383, in _request
    _raise_response_exceptions(response)
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/internal.py", line 172, in _raise_response_exceptions
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 831, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `r.get_front_page()` returns a lazily evaluated object, and you only need the first element from that object.  If so, try the following:

```
import time

def crawlReddit():                                                     
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='challenge')             # PRAW object
    front_page = r.get_front_page()
    try:
        first_headline = front_page.next() # Get the first item from front_page
    except HTTPError:
        return None
    else:
        return first_headline.title


def main():
    max_attempts = 3
    attempts = 1
    headline = crawlReddit()
    while not headline and attempts < max_attempts:
        time.sleep(1)  # Make the program wait a bit before resending request
        headline = crawlReddit()
        attempts += 1
    if not headline:
        print "Request failed after {} attempts".format(max_attempts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit** The code now attempts to access the data a maximum of 3 times, with one second intervals between failed attempts.  After the third try it gives up.  The server may be offline etc.

Comment: thanks. and how would I get it to try a second time upon failing?

Comment: if you have crawlReddit return None in the case of an exception, then you might make it check x many times after a time.sleep `while not headline`.

Comment: ah. Is there any way you could provide sample code for this? I'm not too familiar with this feature of Python. Thank you!

Comment: btw, can you confirm that r.get_front_page() returns a generator rather than a list?  I double-checked the documentation but I don't see it being specified.

Comment: yep I just tried out your code and it works perfectly.